# CSS creating a horizontal navigation bar - `li`s vs. `div`s

Tags: css

Which is the semantically better way to do this? Floating `li` elements inside a `ul` or just float `div`s inside an 'outer' div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a list would be more semantically correct, as the content represents a list of navigation items. Divs are just division/placeholder containers, often used for styling.

Answer (score 1):

For html4 use a list as Mic said.

For new html5 there is a `<nav>` element to wrap your list in, which is semanticaly better.

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You improve it width the `role` attribute. Like this `<ul role="navigation">`